# Fill Datagridview rows from Datatable according to a DatagridviewComboboxCell value

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a `Datagridview` with `DatagridviewComboboxColumn` which is binded to a `datasource`, What i want is when i choose a value from this 
`DatagridviewComboboxColumn` the other cells of the row will display the values corresponding to `DatagridviewComboboxColumn` from the `datatable`.

here is the code i have tried:

```
public Form2()
{
   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbcolumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
   DataGridView2.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing);                           
}

private void DataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string item = null;
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;

        if (cb.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
        {
            item = cb.SelectedValue.ToString();
            fillDGV(item, DataGridView2.CurrentRow);
        }
}

private void fillDGV(string code, DataGridViewRow row)
{            
        SqlConnection con5 = new SqlConnection();
        con5.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con5.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT LibArticle, Stock FROM Article WHERE CodeArticle = @CodeArticle", con5);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeArticle", code);

        SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (read.Read())
        {
            row.Cells[1].Value = read[0].ToString();
            row.Cells[2].Value = read[1].ToString();
        }                        
}
```

This code works perfectly only for the first row of the `datagridview`. In the second row i got this error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in this line:

> if (cb.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)

How to fix it??

Comment: `if (cb.SelectedValue != null)` `ToString()` is a horrible anti-pattern

Comment: try `if (cb.SelectedValue != null)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the error i spent a full day and you solve it quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if (cb.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)

change your if condition to

```
if (cb.SelectedValue != null)
```